# Special Characters when parsing Guardian API

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am creating a news app that shows a list of news using Guardian API, and I am using Volley for networking. But the problem is when I get strings from JSON Objects and storing them in model class directly, some of them come with special characters when I open the app. I want to get rid of them (see Image)
[image: News App Screen]

I am calling prepareData() method from onCreate()

[Guardian API link](https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=d7262a1a-2583-4342-9b57-85ed0f621416)

```
private void prepareData() {
    //Create request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    //Create new String request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            GUARDIAN_URL,
            response -> {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"TEST: Response Received");
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject response_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                    JSONArray resultArray = response_obj.getJSONArray("results");

                    for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String news_title = jo.getString("webTitle");
                        String author_name = "No author";
                        String section_name = jo.getString("sectionName");
                        String published_date = jo.getString("webPublicationDate");
                        String web_url = jo.getString("webUrl");
                        Log.i("TEST","news-title: "+ news_title + " section: "+section_name+ " date: "+published_date);

                        News news_item = new News(news_title, author_name, section_name, published_date, web_url);
                        news_list.add(news_item);
                    }
                    if (news_list.isEmpty()){
                        //set empty text visible and recycler view GONE if no news found
                        empty_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else {
                        //if news available set empty text to GONE
                        empty_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //RecyclerView adapter
                        mNewsAdapter= new NewsAdapter(news_list,this);
                        //setting adapter with recyclerView
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(mNewsAdapter);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            },
            //Method that handles error in volley
            error -> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    //add string request to request queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your url connection setting. it should be

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

or something like that

```
URLEncoder.encode("Your Special Character", "UTF8");
```

Comment: How can I set connection to Volley request

Comment: I have added another answer. Please take a look at. Sorry for being late.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at here. May this example will help you to understand how to encode in volley request!

```
public class Utf8JsonRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONObject> {
...
@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse (NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String utf8String = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(utf8String), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // log error
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // log error
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

}